# How to push the latest version of your web app using gcloud to make it live

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am currently working on a app that I am hosting on Google Cloud. I tried everything in the documentation but may have had the command 'default_expiration: "30d"' in the app.yaml file. I got rid of it but it won't let me push the latest version of my app to make it live. I tried everything I could think of such as 'gcloud app deploy --promote --stop-previous-version' but to no avail. How can I get the latest version of my code live using Google Cloud App Engine.

Cheers,

**EDIT:**

If I go to the latest version as 'www.version.app-name.appspot.com' it shows the latest version; however, in the App Engine Versions panel, it shows that version with 100% of traffic allocated to it even though when I go to 'www.app-name.appspot.com' it displays a very old version.

I tried deleting all the old versions on the App Engine Versions panel, including the version that is being displayed, and it still shows the old version when going to 'www.app-name.appspot.com' but going to the exact version number displays the correct version. The newest version shows 100% of traffic is being sent there.

Cheers,

Comment: I tried to use 'default_expiration: "5m"' in the app.yaml but it still won't update. Any help is greatly appreciated. In the panel it says all traffic is sourced to the latest version that was updated time-wise last, but, it still doesn't display the latest version even when clicked on in the management console

Comment: Try deploying with a new version, then switch traffic to the new version deployed.

Comment: @Dan Cornilescu Would you be able to post your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @PhilippSh Let's see if it works first, right now it's just a theory :)

Comment: @Dan Cornilescu I tried in the app engine Version Panel to click on the newest version and when I click the link next to it's name it is the newest version but when I migrate 100% of traffic to it it is still the old version when I either click the same link or go to the 'my-app.appspot.com link'

Comment: After removing all the old versions from the App Engine Versions section, leaving only the latest one, it still has the same error. It displays a very old version of the app at 'myapp.appspot.com' even though that version has been deleted a long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now magically works so I will post the steps I did. I managed to debug it and find out that the version with all the traffic according to the App Engine Version panel wasn't the version being displayed, so, I deleted all the old versions on the Version panel and then it still wasn't working. It was still the same error, that the newest version was not being displayed when visiting 'www.app-name.appspot.com' so I waited around half an hour and now it is displaying the correct version at the main address. See the question for more debugging information.

Cheers,

Comment: Most likely caching - possibly on the browser and/or on the google's edge cache.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it on multiple computers so it could be Google's Edge Cache.